# Rails gem: correct place for a controller helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a private gem for Rails which includes a controller helper.

I doubt between these two places for this helper:

- `lib/gem_name/my_helper.rb`
- `app/controllers/concerns/gem_name/my_helper.rb`

What is the correct place for it?

Comment: `helper` suppose to be under `app directory` right. on what moto you wanted to move it to some other places?

Comment: As you said you are working on it for a gem, include it in `lib` folder   [Link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#generate-a-gemified-plugin)

Comment: is the gem a Rails engine or plain gem?

Comment: Plain gem, it only adds some authentication helper methods.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use it in controller `concern`, then include helper module into Application controller

So I will prefer `app/controllers/concerns/gem_name/my_helper.rb` for creating controller helper inside gem.

Comment: I agee +1 if you only use to controller